# Select only year part from dates in a table without duplicates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a huge table with various data, and one column represents date. It's date data type. I want to assign variable with all possible years from that date without any duplicates.

For example:

```
|   dates    |
+------------+
| 2016-04-04 |
| 2016-05-05 |
| 2016-06-06 |
| 2017-05-02 |
| 2017-01-05 |
| 2018-07-05 |
```

I want my variable to look something like this:

```
@years = [2016, 2017, 2018]
```

Comment: Which database you are using?

Comment: @Pavan sqlite in development, pg in prodcution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
years = Model.pluck(:date).map(&:year).uniq
```

Comment: This is it. Just please format it  and I'll accept your answer (CTRL+K to format code)

Comment: @Kunok This is a good answer if the number of rows is small and will remain so.  If the number of rows is large, it's usually better, in order to keep from retrieving too many rows from the database, to cause the database itself to do all the work.  The accepted answer in the linked-to question shows how.